# SVN Web Administration tool

Tags: svn, web-applications

I am looking for a web based tool that will completely manage a SVN server. It must be able to do everything from managing Repos, Users, to providing a Repo Explorer. Both the SVN server & admin tool will need to/are running on Ubuntu

Only other requirement is that it is not Java based like [svn webadmin](http://code.google.com/p/svn-web-admin/)

Thanks for all help.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is [ViewVC](http://www.viewvc.org/), which is a pretty comprehensive repository explorer - you can see different revisions, diffs, etc.  SVN doesn't really have a built-in concept of users - you use whatever underlying authentication system you want, whether that be PAM or something like LDAP through a WebDAV server.  It's written in Python, so should fit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

http://usvn.info/ turned out to be what i was looking for